# How to get number from file in matlab?

Tags: matlab

In my program I want to save the counter value. Like 1 and if the counter increased then 1 will be replace with 2 like that. I created a file `test.txt` and manually entered a number `1`, in the directory and used this code to read that number.

```
f=fopen('test.txt');
cno=fread(f);
cno
fclose(f);
```

But the value of `cno` is in ASCII I guess because its saved like this in file.
I try to used functions like parseInt but didn't work.
Please tell me how to write as well as read a number from file.
Also if there is any other way possible to save that counter value instead of file. I want to retain value even If I close matlab code that's why I am saving it to the file.

Comment: How are you saving the counter to `test.txt`? Does it need to be a `*.txt` file?

Comment: no, It can be of any format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple methods for this. If you don't need to ensure compatibility with external programs, then MATLAB's [`save`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/save.html) and [`load`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/load.html) commands should be more than sufficient.

A basic example:

```
a = 5;
save('test.mat', 'a');

clear a

load('test.mat');
disp(a)
```

See the documentation for `save` for syntax information.

As a general note I would advise calling `load` with an output declared, which will load all of the variables in your saved `*.mat` file into a structure, preventing them from overwriting existing data in your workspace.

Using `test.mat` from the previous example:

```
mydata = load('test.mat');
disp(mydata.a)
```

EDIT: Now, if you wanted to store this to a generic file, the most common method would be to use `fprintf` and `fscanf`:

```
a = 5;

fID = fopen('test.txt', 'w+');
fprintf(fID, '%u', a);
fclose(fID);

clear a

fID = fopen('test.txt', 'r')
a = fscanf(fID, '%u');
fclose(fID);
```

Comment: I have 2 questions, 1) Is the data saved in `.mat` file with variable `a`? 2) I just have to save, update and load only one value, can I update value of a again and again?

Comment: @Arpit 1.) Yes, the variables you choose to save will retain the names they did when you saved them. This is the reason I prefer to use `load` with a declared output, it keeps the loaded variables contained to prevent conflicts and so I know where they came from. 2.) If I'm interpreting your question correctly, yes.

Comment: okay, I got it now and It's working too. Last question the data recieved after loading is still an integer right?

Comment: @Arpit if using `save` and `load`, yes. Loaded variables will be of the same type as they were saved.